# Error in Register.razor: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

I'm doing an application in Blazor (C #) Server-Side. I get the following error in the Register.razor file:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' <> 4__this._dataContext was null. I also get the following warning: Field Register._dataContext is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null.
This error happens to me when I want to save the registration data to the database (click the Register button).

What am I doing wrong?

Register.razor:

```
@page "/register"

@using TestBlazor.Models
@using TestBlazor.Data

@*@inject IToDoListService user*@

<br />
<br />

<h3><b>Register</b></h3>
<br />

<EditForm class="needs-validation" Model="@_user" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit">
    <div class="alert @StatusClass">@StatusMessage</div>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>User name</b></p>
        <input id="username" class="solid" name="username" placeholder="Your username.." @bind-value="_user.UserName" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.UserName)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Password</b></p>
        <input type="password" class="solid" id="password" placeholder="Your password.." @bind-value="_user.Password" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Password)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Email</b></p>
        <input id="email" class="solid" placeholder="you@example.com" @bind-value="_user.Email" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Email)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Company</b></p>
        <input id="company" class="solid" placeholder="Your company.." @bind-value="_user.Company" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Company)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>


    <br />

    <button disabled="@loading" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddUser">

        @if (loading)
        {
            <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
            <NavLink href="/login" class="btn btn-link">Register</NavLink>
        }
        Register
    </button>
    <NavLink href="/login" class="btn btn-link">Login</NavLink>
</EditForm>



@code {
    private User _user = new User();

    private string StatusMessage;
    private string StatusClass;

    private bool loading;
    private readonly AppDbContext _dataContext; //warning this record: Field Register._dataContext is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null.

    //provjeriti: var context = new SchoolContext()


    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        if (loading == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have successfully registered!");
        }

        else
        {
            loading = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Check your information again!");
        }
    }

    //protected void HandleValidSubmit()
    //{
    //    StatusClass = "alert-info";
    //    StatusMessage = " You have successfully registered! Please click the Login button to log in!";

@*}*@


private async void HandleValidSubmit()
{
    try
    {
        _dataContext.User.Add(_user); //error in this record System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' <> 4__this._dataContext was null.

        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        base.StateHasChanged();
    }
    _user = new User();
    base.StateHasChanged();
}


protected void HandleInvalidSubmit()
{
    StatusClass = "alert-danger";
    StatusMessage = " Check your information again!";
}


//public bool doesCompanyExist(string Company)
//{
//    User u = new User();
//    if (u.IsValid(Company))
//        return true;
//    else
//        return false;

//}

}
```

User.cs:

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestBlazor.Data;

namespace TestBlazor.Models
{
    [Table("Users")]
    public class User

    {

        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "UserName is required.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "password must be atleast 8 characters")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Company")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company is required.")]
        [Remote("doesCompanyExist", "Company", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Company already exists. Please enter a different company.")]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        public User GetRegisteredUser()
        {
            return new User
            {
                UserName = UserName,
                Password = Password,
                Email = Email,
                Company = Company,

            };
        }

    }

}
```

AppDbContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestBlazor.Models;

namespace TestBlazor.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext()
        {

        }

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=testblazor;Integrated Security=True;");
            }
        }

        //protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        //{
        //    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        //}

        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }


    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) In your case, `_dataContext` is null. You have to assign a value to it.

Comment: It is clear from your code that `_dataContext` is not initialized... so all you need to do is initialized... did you do that? What's the issue you are facing there?

Comment: @SomeBody I’ve watched it before, but I haven’t been able to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I tried with this private AppDbContext = new AppDbContext (); and this private readonly AppDbContext _dataContext;.

Comment: @Katarina Maybe also your `User` property of your `_dataContext` object is null.

Comment: @SomeBody Thank you very much for your help. How could this be verified?